# How can I configure a Spring Application to Include the thrown Exception as a message in Error 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have a spring backend application which throws some helpful custom Java exceptions in response to faulty REST API calls, and I have seen tutorials where the thrown exception also shows up as a message value in the returned code 500 internal server error. I'm wondering if there is a way to configure spring such that these thrown exception messages are sent back with the 500 error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using this code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    ResponseEntity onAnyUnknownException(Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Some unknown exception occured", exception);
        Map<String, Object> userResponse = new HashMap<>();
        userResponse.put("ERROR", "Your custom message");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(userResponse);
    }
}
```